# How can I redirect to another URL without changing the URL in the address bar?

Tags: redirect

I want to redirect from:

> domain1.com/demo

To:

> domain2.com/demo

I want the URL in the address bar to still read:

> domain1.com/demo

---

Check the following example

> for example :

I want to create a preview window same like [codecanyon](https://preview.codecanyon.net/item/shopwise-laravel-ecommerce-system/full_screen_preview/28855605?_ga=2.236821697.1136111789.1608560620-1378464894.1591261743) which redirects to: [link](https://shopwise.botble.com/)

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried and what language and server you are using?

Answer (score 0):

In provided example from codecanyon is used **iframe** to show content from other source.

To achieve the same behavior, you should place in source code of your page (domain1.com/demo) `<iframe src="//domain2.com/demo"></iframe>`.

And during user navigation in iframe, parent page and address in browser bar will not be changed.